# Cannot look up into entity framework using in memory list

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm looking up in my entities database using an in memory List but I get this error :

Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

The code Im using is this :

```
dgv.DataSource = (from x in Helper.Ctx.Planner where myList.Contains(x.Customer) select x).Take(100);
```

I researched this issue and found that its suggested I retrieved all the contents using ToList() first but the database is very big, and retrieving the whole thing over the network would take minutes each time.

I am using EF4.1 and VS 2010.

Please any solution?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the Pk key of Customer instead of the complete object.

```
myList.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(x.Customer.Id)
```

Comment: Hi sorry the Customer is just a string field (the customers name) not an object.

Comment: Seems EF4 does not support it like Linq2Sql does, check out this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/ for possible workaround.